# MongoDb Upgrade from 2.6 to 3.0 Issue

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

For some reasons I cannot install MongoDb 3.0 version. What am I missing?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Top of my head. You didn't perform an `apt-get update` first. But wildly off-topic for a programming Q&A site. Ask on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead and make more of an attempt to solve it first please.

Comment: MongoDB only maintains repos for LTS versions, namely Precise Pangolin and Trusty Tahr. Running an outdated release is a Very Bad Idea™. There is no support for Salamander available for over a year, now. Note that there is a typo for the extras, too. It should be "saucy", not "sauscy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace what's in /etc/apt/sources.list entirely with

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
```

From: https://askubuntu.com/questions/572235/404-failed-to-fetch-package

Answer (score 0):

You are using repos that have not been updated with the newest version of mongodb.  Add [their repo](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/) and then update apt-get then trying installing 3.0.1.